# Datatable select linq query on same column with two different condition resulting zero rows

Tags: c#

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> mergedRows = from myRow in _gridData.AsEnumerable()
                                              select myRow;

IEnumerable<DataRow> rows;

rows = from myRow in mergedRows where  
double.Parse(myRow["signalName"].ToString())> 1800 &&
                                       select myRow;

mergedRows = rows;
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows;//reinitializing 
rows = from myRow in mergedRows where
double.Parse(myRow["signalName"].ToString()) < 2400
                                       select myRow;
```

above one gives me zero results, which is wrong..
when the query is running second time mergedRows has the resulted data after the first condition. Still i dont get the results after the second query execution.

But the same query with combined condition works fine.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> mergedRows = from myRow in _gridData.AsEnumerable()
                                              select myRow;
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows;

rows = from myRow in mergedRows  where 
double.Parse(myRow[signalName].ToString()) > 1800 &&
double.Parse(myRow[signalName].ToString()) < 2400
                                       select myRow;
```

this one give me exact results which are correct.

Can you please explain why..

Comment: Can you post or check what's the value of your `_gridData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be running into a "[deferred execution](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/03/16/understanding-linq-to-objects-6-deferred-execution.aspx)" problem.

This contains your "source" data

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> mergedRows = from myRow in _gridData.AsEnumerable()
                                          select myRow;
```

This contains your query but hasn't actually been executed yet.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = from myRow in mergedRows where  
                            double.Parse(myRow["signalName"].ToString())> 1800 
                            select myRow;
```

And then this overwrites your source data with the unexecuted query

```
mergedRows = rows;
```

You could try to greedily execute your queries by wrapping them in .ToList();

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> mergedRows = from myRow in _gridData.AsEnumerable()
                                              select myRow;

var rows = (from myRow in mergedRows where  
            double.Parse(myRow["signalName"].ToString())> 1800 &&
            select myRow).ToList();

mergedRows = rows;


rows = (from myRow in mergedRows where
        double.Parse(myRow["signalName"].ToString()) < 2400
        select myRow).ToList();
```

If you're always going to execute both filters, I'd consider just cleaning up the whole thing and merging all your work into one query.

```
private double SafeParse(string s)
{
    double d;
    return double.TryParse(s, out d) ? d : 0; //return zero if the value is unparsable
}


var results = (from myRow in _gridData.AsEnumerable()
              let d = SafeParse(myRow[signalName].ToString()) 
              where d > 1800 && d < 2400
              select myRow).ToList();
```